# Can't resolve libraries after importing project from different computer

Tags: android, android-studio

after importing my project from my old computer to my new computer gradle fails to build.

My best guess is that it has to do with using the alpha 28 library. Since a previous version of the project that doesn't will still build

```
def SLVersion = '28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${SLVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${SLVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${SLVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${SLVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:design:${SLVersion}"
```

I've tried copying most of the files from my Android folder and AppData folder hoping it gets it to work, but it still doesn't

I get the error

```
Failed to resolve: design
Open File


Failed to resolve: recyclerview-v7
Open File
```

And so on and so on with the libraries. So i want to use my new computer, but this has been holding me up for a few weeks. Out of ideas so if anyones got suggestions they are appreciated

Comment: I had a similar problem that took ages to solve, in the end I deleted the caches inside the ~/.gradle folder and downloaded dependencies again.

I'm on the same as you alpha 3 "implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha3'" and "implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'"

Comment: @Elletlar Awesome that worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Glad it is working :)  I wasn't sure if it was the same one since there are so many subtle Gradle problems that can happen.  I'll move it to the solution. Cheers.

Comment: Hi Bruce. Can you accept the solution below please. Thanks!

Comment: @Elletlar yea no problem, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem that took ages to solve, in the end I deleted the caches inside the ~/.gradle folder and downloaded dependencies again.

- API 28 alpha 3
- Gradle Version: 4.4
- Android Plugin Version: 3.1.3